# How to return a list of words from a text file in python

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

I want to return all words found in a text file. This is the code i have so far.

```
def get_dictionary_word_list():
    f = open('dictionary.txt')
    for word in f.read().split():
        print(word)
```

It works using the print fucntion but instead of printing the words i want to return all the words in the text file. Using return it only shows 'aa' and not the words in the file. Im not sure why it's not working with return?

Comment: do you want all 2 choices of words from your file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you used return in the loop, it returned on the first iteration and you only got back the first word.

What you want is an aggregation of the words - or better yet, return the array you got back from splitting the words. You may want to sanitize line breaks.

```
def get_dictionary_word_list():
    # with context manager assures us the
    # file will be closed when leaving the scope
    with open('dictionary.txt') as f:
        # return the split results, which is all the words in the file.
        return f.read().split()
```

To get a dictionary back, you can use this (takes care of line breaks):

```
def get_dictionary_word_list():
    # with context manager assures us the
    # file will be closed when leaving the scope

    with open('dictionary.txt') as f:
        # create a  dictionary object to return
        result = dict()
        for line in f.read().splitlines():
            # split the line to a key - value.
            k, v = line.split()
            # add the key - value to the dictionary object
            result[k]  = v
        return result
```

To get key,value items back, you can use something like this to return a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) (keep in mind the file will be left open as long as the generator remains open). You can modify it to return just words if that's what you want, it's pretty straightforward:

```
def get_dictionary_word_list():
    # with context manager assures us the
    # file will be closed when leaving the scope
    with open('dictionary.txt') as f:
        for line in f.read().splitlines():
            # yield a tuple (key, value)
            yield tuple(line.split())
```

Example output for the first function:

```
xxxx:~$ cat dictionary.txt 
a asd
b bsd
c csd
xxxx:~$ cat ld.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python

def get_dictionary_word_list():
    # with context manager assures us the
    # file will be closed when leaving the scope
    with open('dictionary.txt') as f:
        # return the split results, which is all the words in the file.
        return f.read().split()

print get_dictionary_word_list()
xxxx:~$ ./ld.py 
['a', 'asd', 'b', 'bsd', 'c', 'csd']
```

Comment: It's not what he is asking for.

Comment: What **is** he asking then? It seems like he used return instead of print which stopped the loop and returned the first word alone.

Comment: @reutsharabani I just want a simple function that returns all the words stored in a file. I used the first code you mentioned but it didn't return any words it was blank? My code works but doesnt work with the return function

Comment: @sc14sd it worked for me. It must return SOMETHING if there is in fact something in the file. I've added example output.

Comment: @ReutSharabani Ah yes it does work infact! Thank you. It was because there were quite alot of words in the file and it just took  a little longer.

Comment: So you have the generator you can use, which is perfect for big files! I'll add a link for an explanation on generator :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
def get_dictionary_word_list(fname):
    with open(fname) as fh:
        return set(fh.read().split())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_dictionary_word_list():
    f = open('dictionary.txt')
    ll=[]
    for word in f.read().split():
        ll.append(word)
    return ll
```

Try through a list

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this:-

```
def func():
    with open('new.txt') as f:
        return f.read() # returns complete file,

with open('out.txt', 'w+') as w:
    w.write(func())
    w.seek(0)
    print w.read()
```

with `Generators`:-

```
def func():
    with open('new.txt') as f:
        yield f.read()
data = func()
with open('out2.txt', 'w+') as w:
    for line in data:
        w.write(line) #or you may use  map(w.write, line)
        w.seek(0)
        print w.read()
```